# Square wave from high voltage power supply (5kV)

Tags: high-voltage, actuator, square

I working on a project involving dielectric elastomer actuators and need to generate a square wave from a 5kV power supply (SRS PS350). The operating frequency will be 0-50Hz. What's one circuit I could use to achieve this?

Comment: My opinion: if you have to **ask** what circuit you need for 5 kV then this isn't something you can or should do yourself. Circuits that work at 5 kV are for **specialists only**. I have plenty (30 years) of experience with low voltage circuits but I would not even consider doing anything with 5 kV without proper studying and training. Also, 5 kV is **LETHAL** so proper training to deal with that is also needed.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie that being said, that power supply has a 10 µA current limiting tripping current, so you *can* use it quite safely. Mrino: Be sure to know how to limit the current to *the lowest current that's still useful*, and know how to ground everything that could save you from a lightning strike. Thanks.

Comment: Does it absolutely have to be square, or could you just make a nice sinewave and put it through a step-up transformer?

Comment: @MarcusMüller *that power supply has a 10 µA current limiting tripping current* OK, I didn't see that. But in my opinion that 10 uA will make it a challenge to design a circuit as it has to consume less than 10 uA. Also, if bypass capacitors are needed (to absurb current spikes above 10 uA) then safety could be compromised as the caps will be able to deliver more than 10 uA.

Answer (score 1):

The classical circuit for flipping polarities of a DC current is the **H-Bridge**. (Really, plenty of material on that out there.)

The trick will be finding a semiconductor switch rated for 5 kV (and more, considering there will be flyback voltage spikes).

There's IGBTs rated for that voltage, but chances are you won't even have *enough* current to make them operate reliably. Also, cost...

So, I guess you'll want to use a stack of MOSFETs on each leg of your H-Bridge, and control them using optocouplers. There's also optocouplers with MOSFETs outputs, but I don't know whether these exist for your voltages.

Comment: Used to be plenty of high voltage BJTs used in old tv horizontal flybacks. But they are getting hard to find. There are some new designs I recently read about (a year ago) and if I can recall where I'll mention them. They were supporting up to 25 kV, if memory serves. Unique, I felt at the time and I was considering calling the supplier to get some. But I never followed up.